# Excel - Find starting month and repeat the value n numbers

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to find the value (column F) based on the starting month (column G) and repeat the value **n** times based on column E. The value of the monthly amount is given by =B5/E5. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToZOy.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in H5:

```
 =IF(AND(H$3<=$G5+$E5-1,H$3>=$E5),$F5,"")
```

And copy over and down.

Comment: In this case, it works partially. Based on my example, the starting month is 1 which is Dec-17 and the billing period 5 which means I want the value 40 displayed since Dec-17 till Apr-18, then May-18 etc should be blank. If the starting month was 2 I want the value being populated since Jan-18 instead of Dec-17 which should be blank and continue till n number displayed in the billing period.

Comment: I found the issue, $G5+$E5-1 changed to  $E5+$G5-1 Full formula: `=IF(AND(H$3<=$E5+$G5-1,H$3>=$G5),$F5,"")` Thank you! @Scott Craner